# Android: OutOfMemory Exception in app that reopens activity

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-activity

I am writing an Android app that allows recorded files to be played back while performing some signal processing on the data.

A file is selected from a listview, this launches a new activity where playback and processing occurs. In the onBackPressed method I call finish to end the activity and return to the list view, where the user can select another file.

All works well when selecting a small file several times or a large file once, however when a large file is selected again an OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown.

I have used the DDMS to see my memory heap and it is clear that the memory from the activity is not released when returning to the list view. It accumulates based on the size of the file being loaded.

Despite extensive research I cant work out where the memory leak is coming from. I have looked into Bitmap and Context references as the causes, however these seem do not to be the issue. File loading itself does also not appear to be the issue as I have another similar activity that uses real-time audio acquired from the mic.

1) What could be the cause of the memory leak?

2) How do I ensure that an activity's memory is freed when finish/ondestroy is called.

Comment: Do you explicitly close the file when you finish the activity?

Comment: Ye, I close the file (pretty sure the file itself is not the problem).  I created a simple test app where all I do is load an new activity and fill it with lots of data (a float 5million elements big). OnBackPressed I call finish. This too causes a similar out of memory exception, calling system.gc fixes the problem in this case. However in my actual application system.gc doesn't seem to have the same effect. I know system.gc is not a directive, but a suggestion.

Comment: Finishing activity without closing files/db/ports etc you opened for stuff.

Comment: There is no gurantee that after calling system.gc(), gc will release the memory. It just makes the memory used by the activity eligible for gcollection

Comment: I have sort of solved the issue. 1) Debug mode was preventing garbage collection...this was the issue when using small files. 2) With large files it seems that the app can't handle loading a large file (more than 1/2 of max memory) one after another. Even though the old data should be garbage collected. My workaround is to load a 'dummy' small file inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach 'WeakReference' components to your large data chunks.  This would release old associated memory chunks that you have held when they are needed.  So after another file gets/requests memory it would release those old 'WeakReference' chunks and your memory problem should be solved in that manner.  This should work since it seems as though you only need the file for the specified time and with this approach you can just let the system worry about when to release it without having to worry.

Comment: Thanks, Just tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: If you have only assigned weak references to your large memory chunks then that denotes that the memory from your files is not the problem.  It probably resides in accidental context leaks or a recursive nature that is causing the problem.  You will have to probably post stack traces and/or code.